# Why the second variable takes the value of the firs ? while the blocks are independent

Tags: java

I AM a beginner in java and we have learned that if two variables are not in the same block then they are independent of each other.

I don"t understand why the variable `entier2` take false if `entier1` is false

```
System.out.print("enter entier1 : ");
    if (!entree.hasNextInt()) {    
        System.out.println("Enter a number1!");
    } else {
        entier1 = entree.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Entier 1 = " + entier1);
    }

System.out.print("Enter entier2 : ");
    if (!entree.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number2!");
    } else {
        entier2 = entree.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Entier 2 = " + entier2);
    }
```

In first it is the first bloc that is executed and after the second 
And the second bloc take the 'value' of the first if the first is false

---

For a correct example we have :

```
Enter number1 : 45
Entier 1 = 45
Enter number2 : 15
Entier 2 = 15
```

So all is just is perfect beacause I have two number

---

But if `entier1 = "txt"` (so one string) then in result  `entier2 = Enter a number2!`

For exemple the result is :

```
Enter number1 : txt
> Enter a number 1 ! 
Enter number2 : Enter a number 2 !
```

So, the program doesn't verif value of `number2` because it take false, because `number1` is false (which is incorrect)

So, my question is **Why number2 take false if number1 is false?**

*Ps : if the question is unclear, please tell me what can clarify it*

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you can use `entree.next()` and throw result away. then use `while` until get correct number, if you want. if I didn't understand it correctly, please give me more information

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: If enter two number, is right but if enter "string" in first the program stop

Comment: I add answer. I think this what you want.

Comment: Can you reopen my question
It is true that my question was not very comprehensible, so I made many changes to bring clarity to it: title, body.
So I'd like the question to be re-evaluated 
and if you need to change it again, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, You only check for `integer` input with `hasNextInt()` but If condition is not true, you didn't throw away incorrect input and so next condition will check again for that incorrect input for second time and return same result as before. in my code I use `in.nextLine()` so I will empty buffer whether input is correct or not. you can do same with this technique too.
if you want to get correct number and then get second number, you can use this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = getInt(in);
        int num2 = getInt(in);
        System.out.println(num1 + " " + num2);
    }

    public static int getInt(Scanner in) {
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        while (true) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            try {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(line);
                return num;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.print("Enter correct input!!\nEnter nubmer: ");
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this help you. We try to get input until only contains number (nothing more)

Comment: yes, but in my program where are 2 block different.

Comment: So entier2 as nothing link with entier1

Comment: If I understand it correctly, You only check for integer input with `hasNextInt()` but If condition is not true, you didn't throw away incorrect input and so next condition will check again for that incorrect input for second number. in my code I use `in.nextLine()` so I will empty buffer whether input is correct or not. you can do same with this technique too. Did I get it correctly?

Comment: Yes it's right,  it's just a history of buffer ?

Comment: yes. because you don't throw away your buffer and you get same result for second condition.

Comment: So, the value entree keeps the same value if I don't throw the buffer ?

Comment: yes. because you use 'hasNextInt()` and it only check buffer from start until find a number from start. if your input is "123" it returns true but for getting result you must use `nextInt()`. However as far I know, it return true for "123TTT" too. so my answer is better for handle that.

Comment: So ok thank you, for your explanation